# How to improve Dart performance of data conversion to/from binary?

Tags: performance, dart, data-conversion

Doing some consulting work for a bigger German companies Future Technologies Group I have ported about 6000 lines of Java server side software to Dart. This should help to answer the question whether Dart can efficiently be used on the server. (Which itself would give a green light for Dart due to the searched for advantage of having one language for client and server side programming.)

Learning about Dart (which I really enjoyed working with) gave me an expectation of a performance penalty of 30-50% relative to Java but in any case no worse than 100% (twice as slow) which is the cutoff for the decision process mentioned above.

The port went smoothly. I learned a lot. Unit tests were fine. But the performance turned out to be extremly bad ... SEVEN times slower overall compared to the Java program.

Profiling the code revealed two main culprits: data conversion and file I/O. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Before I go back to my client and they cancel their Dart research I would like to search some advice on how to improve things. Let's start with data conversion, the conversion of native Dart data types into various binary formats which can be used for effective transfer and storage of data.

Usually these conversions are simple and very fast because nothing has really to be converted from the used internal format but mostly stored into a buffer. I created a benchmark program which somehow reflects the typical use of these conversions in my program:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:benchmark_harness/benchmark_harness.dart';

// Create a new benchmark by extending BenchmarkBase
class ConversionBenchmark extends BenchmarkBase {

  Uint8List result;

  ConversionBenchmark() : super("Conversion");

  // The benchmark code.
  void run() {
    const int BufSize = 262144; // 256kBytes
    const int SetSize = 64;     // one "typical" set of data, gets repeated
    ByteData buffer = new ByteData(BufSize);
    double doubleContent = 0.0; // used to simulate double content
    int intContent = 0;         // used to simulate int content
    int offset = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < buffer.lengthInBytes / SetSize; j++) {
      // The following represents some "typical" conversion mix:
      buffer.setFloat64(offset, doubleContent); offset += 8; doubleContent += 0.123;
      for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) { // main use case
        buffer.setFloat32(offset, doubleContent); offset += 4; doubleContent += 0.123;
      }
      buffer.setInt32(offset, intContent); offset += 4; intContent++;
      buffer.setInt32(offset, intContent); offset += 4; intContent++;
      buffer.setInt16(offset, intContent); offset += 2; intContent++;
      buffer.setInt16(offset, intContent); offset += 2; intContent++;
      buffer.setInt8(offset, intContent); offset += 1; intContent++;
      buffer.setInt8(offset, intContent); offset += 1; intContent++;
      buffer.buffer.asUint8List(offset).setAll(0, "AsciiStrng".codeUnits); offset += 10;
        // [ByteData] knows no other mechanism to transfer ASCII strings in
      assert((offset % SetSize) == 0); // ensure the example content fits [SetSize] bytes
    }
    result = buffer.buffer.asUint8List(); // only this can be used for further processing
  }
}

main() {
  new ConversionBenchmark().report();
}
```

It is based on the benchmark harness from https://github.com/dart-lang/benchmark_harness. For comparisions I used the following Java program based on a port of the Dart benchmark harness from https://github.com/bono8106/benchmark_harness_java:

```dart
package ylib.tools;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class ConversionBenchmark extends BenchmarkBase {

  public ByteBuffer result;

  public ConversionBenchmark() { super("Conversion"); }

  // The benchmark code.
  @Override protected void run() {
    final int BufSize = 262144; // 256kBytes
    final int SetSize = 64;     // one "typical" set of data, gets repeated
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(BufSize);
    double doubleContent = 0.0; // used to simulate double content
    int intContent = 0;         // used to simulate int content
    for (int j = 0; j < (buffer.capacity() / SetSize); j++) {
      // The following represents some "typical" conversion mix:
      buffer.putDouble(doubleContent); doubleContent += 0.123;
      for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) { // main use case
        buffer.putFloat((float)doubleContent); doubleContent += 0.123;
      }
      buffer.putInt(intContent); intContent++;
      buffer.putInt(intContent); intContent++;
      buffer.putShort((short)intContent); intContent++;
      buffer.putShort((short)intContent); intContent++;
      buffer.put((byte)intContent); intContent++;
      buffer.put((byte)intContent); intContent++;
      buffer.put("AsciiStrng".getBytes());
      //assert((buffer.position() % SetSize) == 0); // ensure the example content fits [SetSize] bytes
    }
    buffer.flip(); // needed for further processing
    result = buffer; // to avoid the compiler optimizing away everything
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ConversionBenchmark().report();
  }
}
```

The Java code runs almost exactly 10 times faster than the Dart code on my Intel Windows 7 machine. Both run in production mode on their respective VMs.

Is there an obvious error in the code? Or are there different Dart classes available to do the job? Any explanation as to why Dart is so much slower with these simple conversions? Or do I have completely wrong expectations with respect to Dart VM performance?

Comment: is conversion to big endian essential for your purposes? we haven't optimized it. passing `Endianness.HOST_ENDIAN` would improve performance by a factor of 3. I am currently looking at the code to see where another factor of 3 is hiding, will get back to you once I know more.

Comment: In the ported software big endian is a given pre-condition to stay compatible with Java generated data sets. For new software it might not be that important. But why does swapping 2 or 4 bytes make such a huge performance difference? That can be done without any additional check, or?

Comment: I see, fair enough. It has a hit because we did not optimize the conversion (nobody before seemed to use it or did not notify us about the slowness): to convert a value BE -> LE we would go jump through way to many hoops. This is not hard to optimize though - I have started on it and should get preliminary numbers today [https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=22107 ].

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov Why need two `slow` native calls (ByteData_ToEndianIntXX and TypedData_SetIntXX)? You can swap bytes in a single call. Or you can simple swap them in Dart. And why need so many checks if native code called only from trusted Dart code?

Comment: @mezoni there is only one slow call `toEndianXYZ`. The other one is inlined by the optimizer. Checks are there because "better safe than sorry", Dart has reflection so it's better to have checks on all native entries to prevent accidental attack through the reflection. Optimizer is there to inline this stuff and elide checks. `_toEndianXYZ` is there because a) it's unoptimized impl, b) there's no non-native way in Dart to swap bytes.

Comment: Another observation (on Intel) is that explicitly passing LITTLE_ENDIAN instead of HOST_ENDIAN improves performance by another factor of 2.

Comment: @sgjesse it's most probably due to our inlining heuristics - we use amount of constants arguments to decide if we want to inline (among other things).  I am going to whitelist these methods for inlining, so that should no longer matter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is true that performance of byte data methods (`ByteData.setXYZ` and `ByteData.getXYZ`) is pretty bad on Dart VM compared to direct typed array access. We started working on the issue and initial results are promising[1].

In the mean time you can work around this unfortunate performance regression by rolling your own conversion to big endian using typed arrays (full code at[2]):

```dart
/// Writer wraps a fixed size Uint8List and writes values into it using
/// big-endian byte order.
class Writer {
  /// Output buffer.
  final Uint8List out;

  /// Current position within [out].
  var position = 0;

  Writer._create(this.out);

  factory Writer(size) {
    final out = new Uint8List(size);
    if (Endianness.HOST_ENDIAN == Endianness.LITTLE_ENDIAN) {
      return new _WriterForLEHost._create(out);
    } else {
      return new _WriterForBEHost._create(out);
    }
  }

  writeFloat64(double v);

}

/// Lists used for data convertion (alias each other).
final Uint8List _convU8 = new Uint8List(8);
final Float32List _convF32 = new Float32List.view(_convU8.buffer);
final Float64List _convF64 = new Float64List.view(_convU8.buffer);

/// Writer used on little-endian host.
class _WriterForLEHost extends Writer {
  _WriterForLEHost._create(out) : super._create(out);

  writeFloat64(double v) {
    _convF64[0] = v;
    out[position + 7] = _convU8[0];
    out[position + 6] = _convU8[1];
    out[position + 5] = _convU8[2];
    out[position + 4] = _convU8[3];
    out[position + 3] = _convU8[4];
    out[position + 2] = _convU8[5];
    out[position + 1] = _convU8[6];
    out[position + 0] = _convU8[7];
    position += 8;
  }
}
```

Benchmarking this manual conversion on your test yields around 6x improvement:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:benchmark_harness/benchmark_harness.dart';
import 'writer.dart';

class ConversionBenchmarkManual extends BenchmarkBase {

  Uint8List result;

  ConversionBenchmarkManual() : super("Conversion (MANUAL)");

  // The benchmark code.
  void run() {
    const int BufSize = 262144; // 256kBytes
    const int SetSize = 64;     // one "typical" set of data, gets repeated

    final w = new Writer(BufSize);

    double doubleContent = 0.0; // used to simulate double content
    int intContent = 0;         // used to simulate int content
    int offset = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < (BufSize / SetSize); j++) {
      // The following represents some "typical" conversion mix:
      w.writeFloat64(doubleContent); doubleContent += 0.123;
      for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) { // main use case
        w.writeFloat32(doubleContent); doubleContent += 0.123;
      }
      w.writeInt32(intContent); intContent++;
      w.writeInt32(intContent); intContent++;
      w.writeInt16(intContent); intContent++;
      w.writeInt16(intContent); intContent++;
      w.writeInt8(intContent);  intContent++;
      w.writeInt8(intContent);  intContent++;
      w.writeString("AsciiStrng");
      assert((offset % SetSize) == 0); // ensure the example content fits [SetSize] bytes
    }
    result = w.out; // only this can be used for further processing
  }
}
```

[1] https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=22107

[2] https://gist.github.com/mraleph/4eb5ccbb38904075141e

Comment: I can confirm the improvements in the benchmark program. Still have to adapt my server software package. I have done the same benchmarks for reading binary data and here the difference to the Java version is even worse: 12 times slower. I will try to create a reader similar to your writer or have already done something like that?

Comment: @TinaHildebrandt I haven't done it - but it's similar (just invert `writeXYZ` methods). Ping me if you have any trouble. And sorry for the performance issues, we'll get them sorted out.

Answer (score 4):

I want to add some details on how I have finally solved the performance problem and how the results look like.

First I used the approach postet by Vyacheslav Egorov and developed from it my own data converter class which provides conversions in both directions. It is still not production code but it worked very well for my server software port and therefore I have appended it below. I intentionally kept the [buffer] a public variable. This might not make for a perfect encapsulation but allows for an easy direct write into and read from the buffer, e.g. via a [RandomAccessFile.readInto] and [RandomAccessFile.writeFrom]. All plain and efficient!

It really turned out that these data conversions where the culprit for the slow initial performance of seven times slower than the Java version. With the change the performance gap narrowed considerably. The Dart version of the 6000 lines server application now trails the Java version by just about 30%. Better than I expected from a language with such a flexible typing concept. That will leave Dart in good position for my customers future technology decisions.

In my eyes having one language for client and server applications could be one very good argument for Dart.

And here comes the code for the data converter as used for this project:

```dart
part of ylib;

/// [DataConverter] wraps a fixed size [Uint8List] and converts values from and into it
/// using big-endian byte order.
///
abstract class DataConverter {
  /// Buffer.
  final Uint8List buffer;

  /// Current position within [buffer].
  int _position = 0;

  DataConverter._create(this.buffer);

  /// Creates the converter with its associated [buffer].
  ///
  factory DataConverter(size) {
    final out = new Uint8List(size);
    if (Endianness.HOST_ENDIAN == Endianness.LITTLE_ENDIAN) {
      return new _ConverterForLEHost._create(out);
    } else {
      return new _ConverterForBEHost._create(out);
    }
  }

  int get length => buffer.length;

  int get position => _position;

  set position(int position) {
    if ((position < 0) || (position > buffer.lengthInBytes)) throw new ArgumentError(position);
    _position = position;
  }

  double getFloat64();

  putFloat64(double v);

  double getFloat32();

  putFloat32(double v);

  static const int _MaxSignedInt64plus1 = 9223372036854775808;
  static const int _MaxSignedInt32plus1 = 2147483648;
  static const int _MaxSignedInt16plus1 = 32768;
  static const int _MaxSignedInt8plus1 = 128;

  int getInt64() {
    int v =
      buffer[_position + 7] | (buffer[_position + 6] << 8) | (buffer[_position + 5] << 16) |
      (buffer[_position + 4] << 24) | (buffer[_position + 3] << 32) |
      (buffer[_position + 2] << 40) | (buffer[_position + 1] << 48) | (buffer[_position] << 56);
    _position += 8;
    if (v >= _MaxSignedInt64plus1) v -= 2 * _MaxSignedInt64plus1;
    return v;
  }

  putInt64(int v) {
    assert((v < _MaxSignedInt64plus1) && (v >= -_MaxSignedInt64plus1));
    buffer[_position + 7] = v;
    buffer[_position + 6] = (v >> 8);
    buffer[_position + 5] = (v >> 16);
    buffer[_position + 4] = (v >> 24);
    buffer[_position + 3] = (v >> 32);
    buffer[_position + 2] = (v >> 40);
    buffer[_position + 1] = (v >> 48);
    buffer[_position + 0] = (v >> 56);
    _position += 8;
  }

  int getInt32() {
    int v = buffer[_position + 3] | (buffer[_position + 2] << 8) | (buffer[_position + 1] << 16) |
            (buffer[_position] << 24);
    _position += 4;
    if (v >= _MaxSignedInt32plus1) v -= 2 * _MaxSignedInt32plus1;
    return v;
  }

  putInt32(int v) {
    assert((v < _MaxSignedInt32plus1) && (v >= -_MaxSignedInt32plus1));
    buffer[_position + 3] = v;
    buffer[_position + 2] = (v >> 8);
    buffer[_position + 1] = (v >> 16);
    buffer[_position + 0] = (v >> 24);
    _position += 4;
  }

//  The following code which uses the 'double' conversion methods works but is about 50% slower!
//
//  final Int32List _convI32 = new Int32List.view(_convU8.buffer);
//
//  int getInt32() {
//    _convU8[0] = out[_position + 0]; _convU8[1] = out[_position + 1];
//    _convU8[2] = out[_position + 2]; _convU8[3] = out[_position + 3];
//    _position += 4;
//    return _convI32[0];
//  }
//
//  putInt32(int v) {
//    _convI32[0] = v;
//    out[_position + 0] = _convU8[0]; out[_position + 1] = _convU8[1];
//    out[_position + 2] = _convU8[2]; out[_position + 3] = _convU8[3];
//    _position += 4;
//  }

  int getInt16() {
    int v = buffer[_position + 1] | (buffer[_position] << 8);
    _position += 2;
    if (v >= _MaxSignedInt16plus1) v -= 2 * _MaxSignedInt16plus1;
    return v;
  }

  putInt16(int v) {
    assert((v < _MaxSignedInt16plus1) && (v >= -_MaxSignedInt16plus1));
    buffer[_position + 1] = v;
    buffer[_position + 0] = (v >> 8);
    _position += 2;
  }

  int getInt8() {
    int v = buffer[_position++];
    if (v >= _MaxSignedInt8plus1) v -= 2 * _MaxSignedInt8plus1;
    return v;
  }

  putInt8(int v) {
    assert((v < _MaxSignedInt8plus1) && (v >= -_MaxSignedInt8plus1));
    buffer[_position] = v;
    _position++;
  }

  String getString(int length) {
    String s = new String.fromCharCodes(buffer, _position, _position + length);
    _position += length;
    return s;
  }

  putString(String str) {
    buffer.setAll(_position, str.codeUnits);
    _position += str.codeUnits.length;
  }
}

/// Lists used for data convertion (alias each other).
final Uint8List _convU8 = new Uint8List(8);
final Float32List _convF32 = new Float32List.view(_convU8.buffer);
final Float64List _convF64 = new Float64List.view(_convU8.buffer);

/// Writer used on little-endian host.
class _ConverterForLEHost extends DataConverter {
  _ConverterForLEHost._create(out) : super._create(out);

  double getFloat64() {
    _convU8[0] = buffer[_position + 7]; _convU8[1] = buffer[_position + 6];
    _convU8[2] = buffer[_position + 5]; _convU8[3] = buffer[_position + 4];
    _convU8[4] = buffer[_position + 3]; _convU8[5] = buffer[_position + 2];
    _convU8[6] = buffer[_position + 1]; _convU8[7] = buffer[_position + 0];
    _position += 8;
    return _convF64[0];
  }

  putFloat64(double v) {
    _convF64[0] = v;
    buffer[_position + 7] = _convU8[0]; buffer[_position + 6] = _convU8[1];
    buffer[_position + 5] = _convU8[2]; buffer[_position + 4] = _convU8[3];
    buffer[_position + 3] = _convU8[4]; buffer[_position + 2] = _convU8[5];
    buffer[_position + 1] = _convU8[6]; buffer[_position + 0] = _convU8[7];
    _position += 8;
  }

  double getFloat32() {
    _convU8[0] = buffer[_position + 3]; _convU8[1] = buffer[_position + 2];
    _convU8[2] = buffer[_position + 1]; _convU8[3] = buffer[_position + 0];
    _position += 4;
    return _convF32[0];
  }

  putFloat32(double v) {
    _convF32[0] = v;
    assert(_convF32[0].isFinite || !v.isFinite); // overflow check
    buffer[_position + 3] = _convU8[0]; buffer[_position + 2] = _convU8[1];
    buffer[_position + 1] = _convU8[2]; buffer[_position + 0] = _convU8[3];
    _position += 4;
  }
}


/// Writer used on the big-endian host.
class _ConverterForBEHost extends DataConverter {
  _ConverterForBEHost._create(out) : super._create(out);

  double getFloat64() {
    _convU8[0] = buffer[_position + 0]; _convU8[1] = buffer[_position + 1];
    _convU8[2] = buffer[_position + 2]; _convU8[3] = buffer[_position + 3];
    _convU8[4] = buffer[_position + 4]; _convU8[5] = buffer[_position + 5];
    _convU8[6] = buffer[_position + 6]; _convU8[7] = buffer[_position + 7];
    _position += 8;
    return _convF64[0];
  }

  putFloat64(double v) {
    _convF64[0] = v;
    buffer[_position + 0] = _convU8[0]; buffer[_position + 1] = _convU8[1];
    buffer[_position + 2] = _convU8[2]; buffer[_position + 3] = _convU8[3];
    buffer[_position + 4] = _convU8[4]; buffer[_position + 5] = _convU8[5];
    buffer[_position + 6] = _convU8[6]; buffer[_position + 7] = _convU8[7];
    _position += 8;
  }

  double getFloat32() {
    _convU8[0] = buffer[_position + 0]; _convU8[1] = buffer[_position + 1];
    _convU8[2] = buffer[_position + 2]; _convU8[3] = buffer[_position + 3];
    _position += 4;
    return _convF32[0];
  }

  putFloat32(double v) {
    _convF32[0] = v;
    assert(_convF32[0].isFinite || !v.isFinite); // overflow check
    buffer[_position + 0] = _convU8[0]; buffer[_position + 1] = _convU8[1];
    buffer[_position + 2] = _convU8[2]; buffer[_position + 3] = _convU8[3];
    _position += 4;
  }
}
```

And a very small and basic test unit:

```dart
import 'package:ylib/ylib.dart';
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';

// -------- Test program for [DataConverter]: --------

void main() {
  DataConverter dc = new DataConverter(100);
  test('Float64', () {
    double d1 = 1.246e370, d2 = -0.0000745687436849437;
    dc.position = 0;
    dc..putFloat64(d1)..putFloat64(d2);
    dc.position = 0; // reset it
    expect(dc.getFloat64(), d1);
    expect(dc.getFloat64(), d2);
  });
  test('Float32', () {
    double d1 = -0.43478e32, d2 = -0.0;
    dc.position = 0;
    dc..putFloat32(d1)..putFloat32(d2);
    dc.position = 0; // reset it
    expect(dc.getFloat32(), closeTo(d1, 1.7e24));
    expect(dc.getFloat32(), d2);
  });
  test('Int64', () {
    int i1 = 9223372036854775807, i2 = -22337203685477580;
    dc.position = 3;
    dc..putInt64(i1)..putInt64(i2);
    dc.position = 3; // reset it
    expect(dc.getInt64(), i1);
    expect(dc.getInt64(), i2);
  });
  test('Int32_16_8', () {
    int i1 = 192233720, i2 = -7233, i3 = 32, i4 = -17;
    dc.position = 0;
    dc..putInt32(i1)..putInt16(i2)..putInt8(i3)..putInt32(i4);
    dc.position = 0; // reset it
    expect(dc.getInt32(), i1);
    expect(dc.getInt16(), i2);
    expect(dc.getInt8(), i3);
    expect(dc.getInt32(), i4);
  });
  test('String', () {
    String s1 = r"922337203!§$%&()=?68547/\75807", s2 = "-22337203685477580Anton";
    int i1 = -33;
    dc.position = 33;
    dc..putString(s1)..putInt8(i1)..putString(s2);
    dc.position = 33; // reset it
    expect(dc.getString(s1.length), s1);
    expect(dc.getInt8(), i1);
    expect(dc.getString(s2.length), s2);
  });
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention: the Java version uses file locks. They do not exist for Dart (and are dearly missed). But they account for only about a 3% performance penalty.

Comment: Thanks for the update! It's pretty exciting! We will work to further close that 30% gap... BTW, I already landed ( https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/detail?r=43038 ) some changes to the `ByteData` methods that speed up your original benchmark by 6x-7x and I have more improvements in the pipeline - once we are done going over this code there should be no need in custom endianess conversion routines.