# How do I use async/HTTP data to return child widgets in an IndexedWidgetBuilder?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm obtaining JSON data over HTTP and displaying it in a ListView. Since it's HTTP, it's all async.

[Here's what I'd like to do:](https://github.com/perlatus/e1547/blob/7ec151b19447b090e3d6db2d8d5fd428a310d1e9/lib/main.dart#L129-L133)

```
var index = new ListView.builder(
  controller: _scrollController,
  itemBuilder: (ctx, i) async {
    _log.fine("loading post $i");
    var p = await _posts[i];
    return p == null ? new PostPreview(p) : null;
  },
);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work since [IndexedWidgetBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/IndexedWidgetBuilder.html) has to be a synchronous function. How do I use a Future to build a child for an IndexedWidgetBuilder? It doesn't seem like there's a way to [wait for the future to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238161/how-to-make-an-asynchronous-dart-call-synchronous/28238318#28238318) synchronously.

Previously, I was loading the data into an array and the IndexedWidgetBuilder function only [checked to see if the list elements existed](https://github.com/perlatus/e1547/blob/db86a0bff343234e96066a0eefb4580bff604b36/lib/main.dart#L134) before returning the child widget.

```
var index = new ListView.builder(
  controller: _scrollController,
  itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
    _log.fine("loading post $i");
    return _posts.length > i ? new PostPreview(_posts[i]) : null;
  },
);
```

This works, but I would like to completely separate the view from the data and asynchronously request the JSON as needed.

This also seems, in my limited experience, like it might be a common use-case. Could an async version of IndexWidgetBuilder be added to flutter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can wait for asynchronous computations using a [`FutureBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). I'd probably change your `PostPreview` to take a `Future` as a constructor argument and put the `FutureBuilder` there, but if you want to leave `PostPreview` as-is, here's how to modify your `itemBuilder`.

```
var index = new ListView.builder(
  controller: _scrollController,
  itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
    return new FutureBuilder(
      future: _posts[i],
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
               ? new PostPreview(snapshot.data)
               : new Container(); // maybe a show placeholder widget?
    );
  },
);
```

The nice thing about `FutureBuilder` is that it takes care of the scenarios where the async request completes and your State has already been disposed.

Comment: It's worth noting that I tried this, and it did work. However, it become too complex and slow (not really due to the FutureBuilder, but my general design).

I ended up just adding a "load more" button rather than trying to hide the pagination from the UI.