# How to write a asynchronous function as a synchronous function with dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to write a asynchronous function as a synchronous function without `Future.then` and `await`,

like Flutter File's delete api

`new File(path).deleteSync();`

But I do not know how to write.

Thank you.

Comment: If you cannot write a synchronous function because the function you call are asynchronous, then trying to squeeze it into a synchronous function is probably not best practice. Maybe you can ask about your case and what you want to achieve? Why do you need a synchronous function?

Comment: Like @nvoigt said. Also the ```deleteSync()``` it's a bad example here and it might confuse you. ```deleteSync``` doesn't use ```deleteAsync``` and makes it ```synced```. It's just a different implementation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238161/how-to-make-an-asynchronous-dart-call-synchronous